# Spring Cannot add foreign key constraint @ManyToOne

Tags: java, mysql, spring, constraints

I've tried to make this Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "rate")
public class Rate {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "rate_id")
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User answerer;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "answer_id")
    private Answer answer;

    @Column(name = "rate_rate")
    private Integer rate = AnswerConstants.MAX_RATE;
    //pluss getter-setters
}
```

Unfortunately, I get this error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to execute schema management to JDBC target [alter table rate add constraint FK8totaejp8tp48clsoikn05fn2 foreign key (answer_id) references answer (answer_id)]

I've Googled for about an hour but I could not found the solution. Can you help me? Why am I getting this?

Additionally: spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update, if I turn it off, it solves the problem but I do not want to do that just because of this.

The Answer class looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "answer")
public class Answer {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "answer_id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "answer_text")
    @NotEmpty
    private String answerText;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User answerCreator;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "question_id")
    private Question question;

    @Column(name = "answer_creation_date")
    @NotNull
    private Date creationDate = new Date();

    @Column(name = "answer_rate")
    private Long answerRate = 1l;
    //plus getters-setters
}
```

And the User class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long id;
    @Column(name = "email")
    @Email(message = "*Please provide a valid Email")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide an email")
    private String email;
    @Column(name = "password")
    @Length(min = 5, message = "*Your password must have at least 5 characters")
    @NotEmpty(message = "*Please provide your password")
    @Transient
    private String password;
    @Column(name = "active")
    private int active;
    @ManyToMany()
    @JoinTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;
    //Plus getters-setters
 }
```

Comment: I have similar issue after upgrading from MySql 5 to 8.0.11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try passing name with referencedColumnName with @JoinColumn annotation. It worked for me.

```
@ManyToOne(optional = false)
@JoinColumn(name = "userTypeId", referencedColumnName = "id",nullable = false)
private UserType userType;
```

My entities were User and UserType where User have an attribute "userTypeId" as the foreign key.